# mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC

Tags: raspicam, firmware

when using NoIR camera:

```
rapivid -v
```

camera work but colour of frame varies with the lighting.

when using IR camera:

```
raspivid -v
```

resulting:

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

I updated the firmware:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo raspi-update
```

I have enabled camera from raspi-config

Comment: What do you get from a `vcgencmd get_camera` command? Run that then edit your question to include the results.

Comment: vcgencmd get_camera gives supported=1 detected=1

Comment: I have two models of rpi camera C and H. C model is working. For H first I had to initilise raspberry pi with camera C and then when I connect H camera I start working but after reboot I again get into the same problem.